# Insertion fail when use entity framework inheritance

Tags: .net, insert, entity-framework-4.1, savechanges

I have two tables, the one named Person, which is abstract, with scalar property "Id" and "Name", where the key "Id" is the primary key. another one named "Student" inherit from Person

I use following code to insert a student to db:

```
    TestModeContainer testModel = new TestModeContainer();
    Student student = testModel.CreateObject<Student>();
    student.Id = "s1";
    student.Grade = "g2";
    student.Name = "Lighter.Spark";
    testModel.AddObject("PersonSet", s);

    testModel.SaveChanges();
```

When I call SaveChanges to save data to database, an System.Data.UpdateException occurred. The inner exception says "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Temp.dbo.PersonSet'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."
Who can tell me why? And how to correct this?

Comment: Are you using EDMX or code first mapping?

Comment: If you open your `Person` entity what value do you see in properties of `StoreGeneratedPattern` for `Id` field?

Comment: StoreGeneratedPattern value for Id field is "Identity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `StoreGeneratedPattern` for your `Id` field to `None`. `Identity` means that value will be set in the database and because of the the value set in the application is never passed to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I now understand the difference.